# iOS: None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specific entitlements

Tags: ios, xcode6, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I'm trying to submit a beta build to the app store for my testflight testers. I've tried building and rebuilding new distribution profiles, but I can't seem to get around this error. I know there are a lot of similar questions on SO but none of the suggested answers seem to work in my case.

[image: grr]

Comment: Wait, you weren't trying to do this today were you?

Comment: yeah, for the past week I've been stuck on this.

Comment: Can you see the entitlements when you look at your provisioning profile in the Member Center? (It's a pain to get to right now but the Member Center is up.)

Comment: I can view my provisioning profiles, but I can't see a view where I can see entitlements specifically. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You would have set the entitlements in the profile when you created them. This image shows how entitlements would appear if you look at your provisioning profiles in Xcode: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxFul.png

Comment: Here's what it looks like on my end — http://i.imgur.com/dBGx3wH.png

Comment: Was that distribution certificate with the month named created using an explicit App ID for the app you're trying to get into the store?

Comment: That was it — see the answer below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this issue by creating a new distribution profile using an explicit App ID for the app instead of the Wildcard App ID I was using.